# Does the campaign unlock or earn anything in MP?

Tags: halo-5-guardians

Question title pretty much explains it. Does anything in the Campaign give rewards for the Multiplayer? Like REQ packs, emblems, armor, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this source](https://www.reddit.com/r/halo/comments/3q7bfg/legendary_campaign_rewards/) you don't get any in-game items or unlocks for playing through the campaign, not even on legendary difficulty. The only rewards for completing the campaign are achievements.